# How do I write the SQL INSERT command in PHP

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

How do I write the SQL INSERT command to add the data in the screenshot provided when I have already created a table?

CREATE TABLE Term (Term_Name VARCHAR(25), Term_StartDate DATE, TermEndDate DATE);

[Term Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNYT9.png)

I've attempted to type in the code, and this is the error that I get; screenshot attached.

[Attempt at INSERT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNYT9.png)

Comment: What have you tried (for SQL Statements)?

Comment: my apologies. i am completely new PHP/SQL, and  I edited my topic so it is more concise with what i am trying to accomplish. thank you.

Comment: Please include all relevant info within the body of the question.  Not only is it easier for us to help, but ensures the question remains valid for all visitors if the links become invalid.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, please refrain from posting screenshots when a copy/paste is best suited.

Comment: How do I copy paste into here? @GillesGouaillardet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close!  You don't want the SELECT to be bundled with the INSERTs.

You simply want the DML (Data Manipulation Language) statements to INSERT the data into the data. So, just use the INSERTS.

Then, use a SELECT statement to obtain the data that you want.

Here is a modified sample of what you did using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84779/1).

Comment: thank you. i learned a lot from your post. it seems that 1. once a table has been created, i do not need the 'table command line' again, i just need to input the data that i want in the SQL. I am learning a lot right now, and it feels good that i have accomplished this. thank you.

Comment: question. How would I write the SQL SELECT command to display all the contents of the "Term" table without listing the column names in the command itself? do i need to use a SELECT DISTINCT syntax?

Comment: Use the wildcard (`*`) to select all columns without a WHERE clause.  (just like the sample SQL Fiddle).  The wildcard `*` is used to select all columns.  The WHERE clause will limit your result set.  The DISTINCT is used within the SELECT statement to obtain a set of distinct values within the result set.  It's useful when you have repeated values within table (or source data set).

Comment: thank you. however, how would i select all the data there, but without the column names of Term_name, Term_StartDate, and Term_EndDate . From what i have currently learned, I've attempted using code: select *
from Term
where Term_StartDate BETWEEN Term_Name AND TermEndDate , however, i am still getting the column names up above.

Comment: You can use the `AS` keyword to rename the output columns.  See this modified [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84779/3)

Comment: thank you very much. it seems that i was in wrong and it is as simple as select * term . ha!

Comment: how would i write the code to just pick the middle row of spring 2 2014 and its start date and end date? i've used SELECT * FROM `Term` WHERE (term_startdate) ='2014-03-14' and (term_startdate)='2014-05-01' , but that went through, yet it did not populate the row.

Comment: That's because you're using `term_startdate` for both conditions in the WHERE clause

Comment: thanks. after a minute of testing, it was actually:  SELECT TERM, Term_StartDate, Term_EndDate FROM Term  WHERE Term='spring 2 2014'